# NoSuchMethodError: No static method (Ljava/io/File;I)Landroid/os/ParcelFileDescriptor;

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native

I am receiving this error, reported through Sentry, in my React Native (v0.63.3) production app on Android Oreo (8.0.0) devices:

[image]

Does anybody have any idea what it could be, why it occurs or how to solve it? I have searched Google and SO but I could not find any other related errors.

Comment: using minify/proguard/r8?

Comment: @DarShan I am using proguard yes, but not minify. I don't know what r8 is?

Comment: if you use ‘minifyEnabled true’ in build.gradle, depending on the version of the Android Studio installed, the minification is done either via Proguard or the new R8.

Comment: Oh I see, very interesting. Will that help me solve my problem if I use minify like that?

Comment: if you enable minify, AS sometimes removes classes that it sees useless or “un-used”, you can either mark required classes with @Keep annotation or search for Proguard tutorials, or you can just disable minify for testing.